# How to add two route command for using two vpn?

Tags: networking, vpn, router

I have two pptp vpn and use them to connect my servers. My Problem is that i cannot use two vpn together. I want useing two vpn together and add route command to route packets to specified server.
first vpn ip range is 192.168.50.0/24, gw is 10.255.254.0
second vpn ip  is 81.91.130.216 , gw is 81.91.128.161

Comment: Is there only one IP address on the second VPN?

Comment: yes, i hav only one ip addres on either two vpn

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your default route is, but whatever it is, if you add these two routes then you should be able to reach both VPNs:

```
sudo route add -net 192.168.50.0/24 gw 10.255.254.0
sudo route add -host 81.91.130.216 gw 81.91.128.161
```

I assume that both gateways are directly reachable from your computer when VPNs are up. If not, you must use addresses that are directly reachable.